# Golang []byte to PHP string

Tags: php, go, binary

I'm currently writing a `[]byte` array with Golang to a file (code below). After I have written it to the file, I want to open the file in PHP and read the string. However, since it's encoded I need to use `unpack`? I'm not sure what format(s) to use.

Here is my Golang code:

```
var jsonlen uint16
// 16KB output buffer
wbuf := bufio.NewWriterSize(os.Stdout, 16384)

// write the magic bytes
fmt.Print(MagicBytes)

// encode and write json
json, err := json.Marshal(Metadata)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Failed to encode the Metadata JSON:", err)
    return
}
jsonlen = uint16(len(json))

err = binary.Write(wbuf, binary.LittleEndian, &jsonlen)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error writing output: ", err)
    return
}

err = binary.Write(wbuf, binary.LittleEndian, &json)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error writing output: ", err)
    return
}
```

Haven't written any permanent PHP code yet so don't have any to show here.

Comment: Rule of thumb: **Never** **ever** fiddle with byte order. Never. Just write the byte slice `json`. If you really need to write the initial length: If possible use decimal (e.g. 4 bytes like "2371") and not a binary format. For more see http://commandcenter.blogspot.ch/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html

Comment: @Volker pretty new to this stuff so no idea what that means sorry, haha. I'm  writing 4 bytes at the start of the file to identify the file, after that a uint16 containing the length of the JSON will be written, after that the JSON will be written and then the rest of the file will continue. It's a modified audio format.

Comment: If you do not know about byte order and that stuff, why are you using binary.Write? Don't do that.

Comment: Start from here: `json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(Metadata)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted this by using:

```
wbuf.Write(json)
```